# Check/Uncheck checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

HTML:

```
<ol>
 <span>Select All<input id='selectall' type="checkbox" onclick='test(this.id);'>
    <ul>
      <span class='selectall'>1.<input type="checkbox" class='selectall'></span>
      <span class='selectall'>2.<input type="checkbox" class='selectall'></span>
      <span class='selectall'>3.<input type="checkbox" class='selectall'></span>
      <span class='selectall'>4.<input type="checkbox" class='selectall'></span>
      <span class='selectall'>5.<input type="checkbox" class='selectall'></span>
    </ul>
 </span>
</ol>
```

JS:

```
function test(clicked_id) {
    if ($("#" + clicked_id).prop("checked", true)) {
        $('#' + clicked_id + ' .' + clicked_id).prop('checked', true);
    } else {
        $('#' + clicked_id + ' .' + clicked_id).prop('checked', false);
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j59eeqgu/

I want to select my main-checbox and to have the other checkboxes checked as well, but I am doing something wrong. When I try to select my main-checkbox, nothing happens.

Comment: Did you properly include jQuery?

Comment: The markup is invalid. A list ([ordered](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ol.html)/[unordered](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ul.html)) is only allowed to contain `<li>` elements

Comment: `function test(clicked_id) {
      $('#' + clicked_id).closest('ol').find('input.' + clicked_id).prop('checked', $("#" + clicked_id).prop("checked"));
    }`

Answer (score 2):

You're using `id` for other check-boxes instead of `class` and use one liner `this.checked` rather then `if condition`,

```
$('#selectall').click(function(){
 $('.selectall[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

FYI, you should use `li` with `ul`

```js
$('#selectall').click(function(){
 $('.selectall[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <span>Select All<input id='selectall' type="checkbox">
            <ul>
        <span class='selectall'>1.<input type="checkbox" class='selectall'></span>
        <span class='selectall'>2.<input type="checkbox" class='selectall'></span>
        <span class='selectall'>3.<input type="checkbox" class='selectall'></span>
        <span class='selectall'>4.<input type="checkbox" class='selectall'></span>
        <span class='selectall'>5.<input type="checkbox" class='selectall'></span>
            </ul>
</span>
```

Comment: You can improve indentation and offer a clean solution by removing all unused html elements and classes..

Comment: I've already mentioned that in my answer, and focused on the main issue.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an working Example.
I also edited your [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pleinx/j59eeqgu/2/)

```js
$(document).on('click', '#selectall', function() {
  if($(this).is(':checked'))
 $(this).parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
  else
    $(this).parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ol>
  <span>Select All<input id='selectall' type="checkbox">
  <ul>
    <span class='selectall'>1.<input type="checkbox" class='selectall'></span>
    <span class='selectall'>2.<input type="checkbox" class='selectall'></span>
    <span class='selectall'>3.<input type="checkbox" class='selectall'></span>
    <span class='selectall'>4.<input type="checkbox" class='selectall'></span>
    <span class='selectall'>5.<input type="checkbox" class='selectall'></span>
  </ul>
  </span>
</ol>
```

**EDIT:**
Update from Comment:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var $selects = $('input[id^="select_"]');
 $selects.on('click', function() {
   var $checkboxes = $(this).parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]');
    $checkboxes.prop('checked', this.checked);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ol>
  <span>Select All<input id='select_0' type="checkbox">
  <ul>
    <span class='selectall'>1.<input type="checkbox" class='selectall'></span>
    <span class='selectall'>2.<input type="checkbox" class='selectall'></span>
  </ul>
  </span>
</ol>
<ol>

  <span>Select All<input id='select_1' type="checkbox">
  <ul>
    <span class='selectall'>1.<input type="checkbox" class='selectall'></span>
    <span class='selectall'>2.<input type="checkbox" class='selectall'></span>
  </ul>
</span>
</ol>
```

**EDIT 2:**
Improve your HTML, you can save much of code and easier to handle. You can add more lists as you needed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 var $list = $('ul.my-whatever');
 var $selects = $list.find('li > input[type="checkbox"]');
  
 $selects.on('click', function() {
   var $checkboxes = $(this).parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]');
    $checkboxes.prop('checked', this.checked);
  });
});
```

```css
ul li {
  margin-bottom: 10px; 
}

ul ul li {
  margin: 0;
}

ul ul {
  list-style: decimal;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="my-whatever">
  <li>
      Select All <input type="checkbox">
      <ul>
        <li>Something <input type="checkbox"></li>
        <li>Something <input type="checkbox"></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
      Select All <input type="checkbox">
      <ul>
        <li>Something <input type="checkbox"></li>
        <li>Something <input type="checkbox"></li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
      Select All <input type="checkbox">
      <ul>
        <li>Something <input type="checkbox"></li>
        <li>Something <input type="checkbox"></li>
      </ul>
  </li>  
</ul>
```

Comment: thank you! it works for now, but what if I would have this:

Comment: How can I make it generic without specifying the id in my function?

Answer (score 0):

Check that in your code you have `span` tags inside `ul`.. You better use `ul`, `li` and add CSS to display inline.. In that way you can clean your html.

To have all checkboxes checked you can add a click event handler function to your `#selectall` checkbox:

```js
$('#selectall').on('click', function(){
  $('input:checkbox').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 8px 0 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Select All <input type="checkbox" id="selectall">
<ul>
  <li>1.<input type="checkbox"></li>
  <li>2.<input type="checkbox"></li>
  <li>3.<input type="checkbox"></li>
  <li>4.<input type="checkbox"></li>
  <li>5.<input type="checkbox"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Yosvel! Do you have an idea how to make it work for more than one list? Let's assume I have more lists and I check a random one.

Comment: Do not unerstand your comment: Right now all input checkboxes `$('input:checkbox')` will be checked on click `#selectall`

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#selectall").change(function() {
  var parentChecked = this.checked;
        $("input.selectall").each(function(){
         $(this).prop("checked",parentChecked);
        });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/j59eeqgu/7/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j59eeqgu/13/ - what if I would have this, how can I make it generic?

Comment: it's more generic now :)

Answer (score 0):

You may try using this jQuery script to add you `checkAll` function to your `checkboxes`.

**HTML**

```
<ol>
  Select All
  <input id='selectall' class="selectall" type="checkbox">
  <ul>
    1.<input type="checkbox" class='selectme'> 
    2.<input type="checkbox" class='selectme'> 
    3.<input type="checkbox" class='selectme'> 
    4.<input type="checkbox" class='selectme'> 
    5.<input type="checkbox" class='selectme'>
  </ul>
</ol>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  $('.selectall').click(function() {
    $('.selectme').prop('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
  });

  $('.selectme').click(function() {
    if ($('.selectme:checked').length == $('.selectme').length) {
      $('.selectall').prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $('.selectall').prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
});
```

I have updated your `class` for `input type="checkbox"`

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shishirmax/oq6h77vp/2/)